# How to solve PHP RuntimeException "Could not open log file" for Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, apache2

I tried to install Typo3 11 with Composer on an Ubuntu 20 with Apache2 as a webserver. PHP 7.4 and MariaDB are running, but PHP has problems to read and write in the Typo3 folder. (PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not open log file

I installed Typo3 with Composer in a directory in home with

```
composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution:^11 project
composer install --no-dev
```

The directory now looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 sudoUser sudoUser   1371 Nov 13 20:36 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 sudoUser sudoUser 271237 Nov 13 20:36 composer.lock
drwxrwsr-x  3 sudoUser sudoUser   4096 Nov 13 20:36 config/
drwxrwxr-x  6 sudoUser sudoUser   4096 Nov 13 20:31 project/
drwxrwxrwx  6 sudoUser sudoUser   4096 Nov 14 09:00 public/
drwxrwsr-x  7 sudoUser sudoUser   4096 Nov 13 20:36 var/
drwxrwxr-x 24 sudoUser sudoUser   4096 Nov 13 20:36 vendor/
```

public looks like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sudoUser sudoUser  815 Nov 13 20:36 index.php
drwxrwxr-x 3 sudoUser sudoUser 4096 Nov 13 20:36 typo3/
drwxrwxr-x 3 sudoUser sudoUser 4096 Nov 13 20:36 typo3conf/
drwxrwsr-x 3 sudoUser sudoUser 4096 Nov 13 20:36 typo3temp/
```

Then I created symlinks in /var/www/html for Apache2, so there are these symlinks to typo3:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Nov 14 14:49 index.php -> typo3src/public/index.php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Nov 14 14:48 typo3src -> /home/sudoUser/t3newProject//
```

Now if I go the start page, I don't get a typo3 landing page, I get a http response 500 (Internal Server Error). So I made a tail for /var/log/apache2/error.log and this is the result:

```
[Mon Nov 14 14:53:47.615281 2022] [php7:warn] [pid 81236] [client 188.102.130.86:55812] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/sudoUser/t3newProject/var/log/typo3_3a57bb40f2.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php on line 181
[Mon Nov 14 14:53:47.615336 2022] [php7:error] [pid 81236] [client 188.102.130.86:55812] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not open log file "/home/sudoUser/t3newEFFORT/var/log/typo3_3a57bb40f2.log" in /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php:183\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php(113): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\Writer\\FileWriter->openLogFile()\n#1 /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php(72): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\Writer\\FileWriter->setLogFile()\n#2 /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php(3221): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\Writer\\FileWriter->__construct()\n#3 /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/LogManager.php(145): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Utility\\GeneralUtility::makeInstance()\n#4 /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/LogManager.php(106): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Log\\LogManager->setWritersForLogger()\n#5 /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/cor in /home/sudoUser/t3newProject/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Writer/FileWriter.php on line 183
```

So I guess it has something to do with system file rwx permissions, but I don't know which folders or files or services I have to give which permissions, because there is no /home/sudoUser/t3newEFFORT/var/log directory. What do I have to change?

Comment: "because there is no /home/sudoUser/t3newEFFORT/var/log directory" - then why not create it?

Comment: @NicoHaase There is still the error, even if I create the directory and the log file manually.

Comment: "Permission denied" - that does not tell you that some file is missing, but that the permissions are not set properly. Which are the current permissions for the file and the directory?

Comment: The file system permissions are read and write for everyone.

Comment: Check again, because this can't be true.
`/home/sudoUser/t3newProject/var/log/typo3_3a57bb40f2.log`
The user of the shell command must be able to read and write this file if you use composer. And later it must have the rights for the Apache if you use the browser with the website.

Answer (score 0):

you said in a comment that permissions are read and write for everyone. But (for security reasons) the apache server should not be everyone. Normaly the apache user is more restricted than everyone.

Therefore it is important to have the correct user or at least usergroup for folders and files. Otherwise TYPO3 (or any script) can not work correct.

In general the apache user has it's own group (like `www`) and if you want to work in the folders of the webserver you should use this group and assign all files and folders to this group.

The usual right mask would be `664` for files and `2775` for folders. in combination with the group www.

You can assign these rights with these commands in the root folder of the instances
(something like `srv/www/htdocs/instance1/`):
*Verify the username (`wwwrun`) and the usergroup(`www`) of your apache user and adapt if necessary!*

```bash
chown wwwrun:www -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 2775 "{}" \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 "{}" \;
```

If TYPO3 can access all files and folders can be checked in the 'Install-Tool' (either with the stand alone script `webdomain/typo3/install.php` or with the backend modules if your user is maintainer for the installation):
`Admin Tools`-> `Environment` -> `Directory Status`

Comment: I've exactly the same problem like OP has mentioned. Typo3 isn't able to write to the log file. I  exactly followed your solution but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. I'm using a fresh installed SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 as operating system and I'm trying to get Typo3 11 running, using the official tutorial from Typo3 webpage. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I found the reason for my problem. My Apache http server is run by user **wwwrun**, but file groups need to be set for user **www**. -.- I'm using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 (SLES15) as operating system.